# Gesture problems with a ViewFlipper that contains a ListView

Tags: android, listview, gesture, viewflipper, swipe

I have a ViewFlipper where one of the views is a ListView. To move back and forth between the views, I have a GestureListener that detects left and right swipes. Sometimes the left & right swipes interfere with the ListView. That is, when I want to switch to the next view by swiping left/right, I may accidentally click on an item in my list.

Is there a good way to prevent this interference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-gestures.html.

The SimpleGestureListener from this page is a great solution to gesture detection. When run in dynamic mode (the default), it intercepts touch events that are determined to be gestures to prevent them from performing other actions. Other touch events are not interfered with.

If you are only interested in swipe gestures I recommend disabling the code for detecting tapping and only listening for swipes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something a little snazzier than a ViewFlipper (something more like the Android home screen) try out this new addition to the Android compatibility libs:  http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html?m=1